# C# CsvHelper - Missing CsvReader.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, csv

I am using CsvHelper to read a .CSV file into an html table. I am using .NET MVC 4 and CsvReader 2.13.2.0. I have tried different versions of CsvHelper and am still getting the same error on this line:

```
var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
```

Error:

[image]

I've looked in the CsvHelper folder and there is just a .dll, debug database, and an XML document. Does anybody know why this file does not exist or if I am using a depreciated CsvHelper method or something. Thanks!

Comment: The error is not that that file is missing. It just mentions the file is missing so it can't show relevant source information for where the exception occurs. Show the full exception message.

Comment: Thats the most information I can get from the error. How would I find the full exception message if it doesn't even hit my catch and just displays the missing file error

Comment: I think if you let it continue after not finding the file, you'll get the exception.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the exception would have to be something to do with the path to the file. Either it's locked and you can't read from it, or more than likely the file can't be found. Try using an absolute path to the file. If you use relative pathing, the path starts from where the executable is running. In the case of debugging, it's usually `\path\to\project\bin\debug\`

Comment: Easy way to find out, put the creation of the `StreamReader` on it's own line. `var reader = new StreamReader( path );` `var csv = new CsvReader( reader );` I think you'll find that the exception is coming from the stream reader line.

Comment: Note that [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.CsvParser/) is about four times faster than CsvHelper. It also supports custom data converters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I would look into LinqToCSV (you can find it on Nuget). With it you can use it to serialize a csv file into an object and use linq to iterate over it. It's very easy to use and since it's a package you won't need to worry about the dll management or the code being deprecated. I've used it in the past, I dont remember the exact syntax but loading the file is something like this:

```
var cc = new CsvContext();
cc.Read<YourModel>(filePath);
```

That will read the csv file into your C# object. Then you can just use it like any other object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, checking it out now

Comment: FYI: `CsvHelper` does this too and is a NuGet package also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I forgot surrounding it with a try-/catch to see the root exception :-). Simple!

```
try 
{
   var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
   //handle it
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
   //handle it
}
```